# conditional fetch

Tags: objective-c, core-data, fetch

I am having trouble fetching a row with specific conditions.

I have an Entity called `UserAccounts` that it contains four attributes: `userName`, `passWord`, `userFullName`, `userLevel`.

For login, I have to get a `passWord` that matches the `userName`. To do this I have two text fields, `userNameTF` and `passWordTF`.
I have to fetch a row with an entity (I am using SQL to compare my request) that matches the `userNameTF.stringValue` and then check if the `passWord` attribute is equal to `passWordTF.stringValue`.

Right now I can take arrays of `userName` and `passWord` from my Core Data store separately using:

```
NSArray *userName = [[userAccountsArray arrangedObjects] valueForKey:@"userName"];   
NSArray *passWord = [[userAccountsArray arrangedObjects] valueForKey:@"passWord"];
```

but these two arrays have no relation to each other, and I can't compare the password with entered username.

I done this before by SQL in VisualStudio using: `select "password" from userAccounts where userName = @"username"` and then comparing the result with the entered password, but I can't find a way to fetch a row with an entity, to do something with its attributes.

Comment: I don't know core data very well but it seems that you are doing things the wrong way around. You should be able to save an entity that has both a username and a password instead of storing usernames and passwords separately. I.e You should store an array of users, not usernames or passwords.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, Yes you right, My  problem is exactly how I can store an Array including 2 attributes of an Entity.  
Anyway, thank you for your quick answer and revision.

Comment: @Prooshani: You're welcome, but I only did the editing, not the reply. You want to message @vakio to talk about that comment.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, heh, yes you right dude.

Comment: @vakio, anyway, thank you dude responding my question and sorry for my bad.

Comment: Sorry, as I said I don't know core data very well. Wait for someone to answer or try to find it in the core data programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Comment: @vakio, I am still waiting for your answers !
I can't understand ! I have one array with 2 attribute `userName` & `passWord` and simply I can't find any relation to find matching userName with appropriate Password in one Array !
it's look crazy to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Finally I found a way solving my problem AGAIN !

Using this code I can retrieve whole attributes of an Entity's record regarding one specific attribute's value.

```
NSArray *userAccounts=[userAccountsArray arrangedObjects]; 
NSArray *matchingAccounts=[userAccounts  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"userName",userNameTF.stringValue]];
NSString *matchedPassWords=[[matchingAccounts valueForKey:@"passWord"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

So I can find the **passWord** related to **userName** that user typed in the userNameTF textfield !

Anyway, this is my way to solve the problem and I think there is more solutions out there.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Core Data is an object graph persistence library; SQL is abstracted away from you, and thinking in SQL terms will often just lead to confusion.

To solve this problem, you want to create a fetch request using a predicate that specifies the user name. If the user exists, it will return an array with one user object (assuming here that names are unique). Then all you have to do is compare your password string with the password property on your user managed object to check if they're the same or not.

Comment: I can fetch userNames and of course they are unique.
So you are going to tell me my fetch result is an array including all attributes ( 4 attributes ) and if the username is unique and available then my passWord attribute is there (as a property) to compare it with the entered password ?

Comment: You're not fetching an array of attributes, you're fetching an array of NSManagedObject (subclasses) of length 1. Each object has the attributes you defined; a user name, password, etc. Remember, Core Data is an object graph, not selecting rows from a database.

Comment: I understand the difference of object graph and row/column in SQL, the problem is I don't know how I can able to fetch some attribute regarding another attribute's condition, So please help me find the answer.

Comment: As I said, setting a predicate on your fetch request is the way to go. See the docs for source code that shows how to set this up.